# What's the best method for iterating through a list and removing elements? The current way I'm doing it causes elements to be skipped

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was using this method, but the for loop skips over the elements. After debugging, I know why it skipped, so I want to know if there's a better method or the proper method.

Here's the code I have:

```
class Birthday:
    name = ''
    date = ''


def __init__(self, name, date):
    self.name = name
    self.date = date

...


   dt1 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1428916628.0)  # Year: 2015
   dt2 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1328916628.0)  # Year: 2012
   dt3 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1228916628.0)  # Year: 2008
   dt4 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1128916628.0)  # Year: 2005
   dt5 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1028916628.0)  # Year: 2002

   b1 = Birthday('John', dt1)
   b2 = Birthday('Larry', dt2)
   b3 = Birthday('David', dt3)
   b4 = Birthday('Joe', dt4)
   b5 = Birthday('Jerry', dt5)

   # Elements are mixed on purpose
   dt_list = [b3, b1, b5, b4, b2]

   # Sort the order of elements by date
   dt_list.sort(key=lambda y: y.date)

   for x in dt_list:
       dt_list.remove(x)
       if len(dt_list) <= 3:
           break

Expected: 2008, 2012, 2015
Result: 2005, 2012, 2015
```

I was thinking of adding this to the first newline of the for loop:

```
x = dt_list[0]
```

But it doesn't feel right.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to create another list using list comprehension. For your case, simply use dt_list[-3:] ?

Comment: @kenbroon that was my original plan, but I believe it's more costly in resources than just removing the individual elements. Sure, the resources are probably so insignificant that it doesn't matter, but I'd really like to learn the efficient way to do this for future purposes.

Comment: Long story short: don't modify an object in place within a loop.

Comment: I believe this is the most efficient way to "chop" a list already. When you see a built-in function, be very doubtful that you can do better, especially when you're not at the expert level yet.

Comment: @user3822: It's not actually more costly to do the listcomp. With the listcomp, you build one new list, iterating the input once. With iterative removal, you have to shift down every element in the `list` once every time you remove an item (so the work is `O(n**2)`, while the listcomp is `O(n)`).

Comment: Also, for this specific case (keeping only the last three elements, whatever they are), your whole loop would be replaced with just `del dt_list[:-3]`, by far the most efficient solution. Or merge the work with the sorting by using `heapq.nlargest` (which is what all of this code really boils down to).

Comment: Thank you, @ShadowRanger, kenbroon, Brad! I appreciate the answers and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mutating during iteration is bad

First of all, it is rarely a good idea to mutate a list over which you are iterating. In particular, this is the source of your current issue. Let's have a look at a similar example.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for x in l:
    l.remove(x)

print(l) # [2, 4]
```

Iterating over a list will return `l[0]`, `l[1]`, `l[2]`... and so on until it hits the end of the list. In particular, this means that if the indexing changes, you might skip some elements. This is what happens here.

If you want to mutate your list, here is how you should do.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

del l[:-3]

print(l) # [3, 4, 5]
```

Although, mutating data is not more time-efficient than creating a new list. When you remove an element from the list, the next elements need to be shifted to the left, which is costly. The above operation is *O(n)* where *n* is the length of the list.

In this case, creating a new list is actually more efficient.

### Slicing

Slicing your list returns a new list and is *O(k)* where *k* is the size of the slice. Thus recovering the three last elements actually runs in constant time.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

new_l = l[-3:]

print(new_l) # [3, 4, 5]
```

Furthermore, since the `list.__getitem__` function is written in C, it is blazing fast compared to a for loop.

It is the fastest way to get only the last three elements.